# Skype:  автоматически принять файл

Tags: c#, skype

Здравствуйте. Как можно автоматически принимать запросы на скачивание файлов в Skype средствами С#? Есть ли такая возможность вообще? Спасибо за помощь заранее. Ссылки на статьи по теме приветствуются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype4COM такой возможности не предоставляет.

Answer (score 0):

Возможность есть.

Сом обьект и описание доступны на самом сайте скайпа.

[Skype для разработчиков](https://support.skype.com/en/category/SKYPE_API/)

Comment: Перерыл всю Skype4COM.dllи не нашел как принять запрос на трансфер файла.